# Format data (Sorry for the large content)

Tags: arrays, bash, sed, awk

I have a file with contents like this:

```
Hostname: Solaris10;
Modified: /software, /nsr, /var, /home;

Hostname: Win2k3sp1;
Modified: "MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS:", "MSSQL$VIM_SQLEXP:";

Hostname: WinXP;
Modified: "D:\\1", "C:\\Inetpub", "C:\\Config.Msi",
      "C:\\Documents and Settings";

Hostname: Win2k3sp1;
Modified: "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer",
      "C:\\Program Files\\Common Files";

Hostname: Centos5;
Modified: /home, /etc, /dev, /boot;

Hostname: WinXP;
Modified: "D:\\Program Files (x86) (x86) (x86)",
      "D:\\Program Files (x86)",
      "D:\\98fdac7656d6632b28";

Hostname: Centos5;
Modified: /opt, /sys, /usr,
        /root;
```

And I need to format it like this:-

```
Centos5,/home
Centos5,/etc
Centos5,/dev
Centos5,/boot
Centos5,/opt
Centos5,/sys
Centos5,/usr
Centos5,/root
Solaris10,/software
Solaris10,/nsr
Solaris10,/var
Solaris10,/home
Win2k3sp1,MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS:
Win2k3sp1,MSSQL$VIM_SQLEXP:
Win2k3sp1,C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer
Win2k3sp1,C:\\Program Files\\Common Files
WinXP,D:\\Program Files (x86) (x86) (x86)
WinXP,D:\\Program Files (x86)
WinXP,D:\\98fdac7656d6632b28
WinXP,D:\\1
WinXP,C:\\Inetpub
WinXP,C:\\Config.Msi
WinXP,C:\\Documents and Settings
```

I can use arrays, text modifiers anything.... but the procedure should be as short/efficient as possible.

I have achieved it using for, while and lot of sed substitutions and I don't like it :( !

Any help will be much appreciated. I can use only 'bash' command on Solaris10/RHEL5

Comment: can you share existing code?

Comment: @anishane, This is to collect only unique entries of names of hosts
<DB fetch command> | sort | uniq | sed -e 's/Hostname: //g' -e 's/ //g' -e 's/;//g' -e 1d >> servers

Then I run <Another DB fetch commands for each host to cehck for modified folders within it>

for HOST in `cat servers`
do
FOLDERS=`<Second DB fetch command per $HOST> | sed -e 's/Modified: //g' -e 's/  //g'`
echo $FOLDERS |tr ',' '\n' | sed -e 's: /:/:g' -e 's/ "/"/g' -e 's/"//g' -e '$d' | while read MODFOL
do
echo -e $HOST,$MODFOL >> All_data
done

Comment: When I use this process I create a connection to DB once to collect all the server names and then create many 'single' connections to DB to fetch deails for each host at a time. Although it's easier to manuipulate data coming from such 'single' connections, but if number of hosts is more, the number of connections created to DB also increase, which I don't want. Primarily becuase I'm collecting the information from a remote host and each time a connection is created, it is slow and sometimes it times out messing the whole set of data.

Comment: btw the fourth entry in your example ends with `,` instead of `;`. are such malformations likely to happen or can we disregard it ?

Comment: @thom, thanks a lot, I've made it proper now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

# newlines and quotes should be ignored,
# so we delete them before we begin
# ';' is a record seperator, we translate this to \n

tr -d '\n\"' | tr '\;' '\n' |\
while IFS=':' read LINE REST
do
    case $LINE in
    "Hostname" ) LABEL="$REST" ;;
    "Modified" ) IFS=','
                  for WORD in $REST
                  do
                      echo "$LABEL,${WORD//\\/\\\\}"
                  done
                  ;;
    esac
done |sort| sed 's/, */,/g'

# sort result and delete superfluous spaces
```

Comment: I think you have missed a '"' in the first 'tr', I've modified ur code and did removal of space before feeding the data to 'while' and looks SWEET !!! Thanks.... I can give only 1 up..otherwise I would have flowed with that :D, current code is below:-
cat <the file> | sed -e 's/  //g' -e 's/: /:/g' -e 's/, /,/g'|tr -d '\n\""'|tr '\;' '\n' |\
while IFS=':' read LINE REST
do
case $LINE in
"Hostname") LABEL="$REST" ;;
"Modified") IFS=','
for WORD in $REST
do
echo "$LABEL,${WORD//\\/\\\\}"
done
;;
esac
done | sort

Comment: There's a small problem with this 'while' loop and separator. If there is a single entry the 'Modified' section such as -> Modified: "D:\\"    then the loop outputs it as -> host,D   it removes the (:\\\) from the output.. :( !

Comment: I have made some single entries you described but I can't reproduce what you found. Can you exactly (byte by byte) copy the code of my answer and try again ? If you still have the same result I would like to see/test the file that triggers this behaviour